# unable to display dynamic image using the war or jar file in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

After clone the project in target linux server Using spring-boot:run command able to upload and view the images form jsp. But using war or jar Unable to store the images under WEB-INF/images folder. Can some one please help on how to store images and retrieve images. And also I need help to store image under the /var/images and retrieve images form /var/images. Images folder should be separate.

Answer (score 1):

You are not following the standard practices.Storing images in /var or WEB_INF is no more used in industry.Can you store the images in dropbox or S3 bucket and include the public URL in your UI code.that will save your IO of your server.This method takes care of compression by default.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But as per requirement. I need to store the images in /var folder. And also I need to retrieve from /var. Please suggest me related to that.